# create adjacency matrix from columns with ids

Tags: r

I have a data.frame of the form...

```
id   f1  f2  f3  f4 n...
01   02  03  .    .  . 
02   01  04  .   05  .
03   01  04  05  .   .
04   05  02  01  .   .
05   02  .   .   .   .
n    02  03 01   .   .
```

and I am trying to recode this as a symmetric adjacency matrix where both columns and rows are distinguished by the member id, and cells represent ties between a pair of ids.

i have tried the igraph package in R, but it seems that the function get.adjacency only takes the first two columns as if they were an edge list.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear what the desired result from this input is. What is the "member id"? What do the different columns represent? What do the rows represent? What do the cell values represent?

Comment: member id is just the column id in the original example. each column represents a set of ids' that are associated with the original "member id" (id). rows are id of each member for whom's other ids' appear to be nominated with... the cell values I want to recover are the incidence of two ids from the original dataset (in example) that appear to be "joint"... hope this helps to clarify the question MrFlick

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Let's assume this is your original data set

```
dd <- data.frame(
    id = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05"), 
    f1 = c("02", "01", "01", "05", "02"),
    f2 = c("03", "04", "04", "02", NA), 
    f3 = c(NA, NA, "05", "01", NA), 
    f4 = c(NA, "05", NA, NA, NA) 
)
```

We can extract something like an edgelist by joining all the values in the `id` column with the non-missing values in the rest of the row. We can do that simply with

```
edges <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, dd[,1], apply(dd[,-1], 1, na.omit)))
```

Let's also extract the unique member ids and the total number of vertices

```
vertices <- unique(as.vector(ids))
N <- length(vertices)
```

Now we can build an adjacency matrix in two ways. We can make one just using matrix indexing

```
adj<-matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=N, dimnames=list(vertices, vertices))
adj[edges]<-1
```

or we could use the igraph library

```
library(igraph)
gg<-simplify(graph.edgelist(edges, directed=F))
get.adjacency(gg)
```

The `igraph` should ensure symmetry (the sample data is not symmetric). It will return

```
   01 02 03 04 05
01  .  1  1  1  .
02  1  .  .  1  1
03  1  .  .  1  1
04  1  1  1  .  1
05  .  1  1  1  .
```